# Controlling one LED via two independently powered ICs without phantom power/exceeding Vmax when one off

Tags: led

I want to control the same LED with:

1. GPIO pin on microcontroller
2. Status pin on charge IC (MCP73831/2) - can use either variant if it makes it easier. I think MCP73831 best.

If charge is finished, I want the LED on always.  If otherwise, off, unless microcontroller says on.

Issue is:  The charge IC is powered via USB, the microcontroller is powered by battery.  STAT1 pin on charge IC has a maximum voltage of VUSB+0.3V.  This is a problem as when USB power is removed as using the below circuit will result in STAT1 having voltage above it's maximum if GPIO goes high while USB is not inserted.  Battery power is always present.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2figBUm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: state diagram for MCP73]

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fO3Z4m.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A couple of diodes will prevent backfeed from one circuit to the other. Schottky diodes will have a smaller voltage drop than regular diodes if that's important to you.*

If the voltages are similar you can use one resistor rather than two.